# Sort tableselect on taxonomy name (not tid)

Tags: 7, forms

So I've got a nice list of products in a tableselect element, like this:

```
$form['nodes'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
);
```

I'm using EntityFieldQuery to make $options and each row is a "product", with a "product type" field which is a taxonomy term. But I want to sort the "product type" column by the taxonomy term rather than the tid (currently they aren't alphabetical and I intend to add more). This is what I've got now:

```
$header = array(
    'Name' => array(...
    ),
    'Product_type' => array(
        'data' => t('Product Type'),
        'type'=>'field',
        'specifier' => array(
            'field'=>'field_product_type',
            'column'=>'tid',
        ),),
    'Price' => array(...),
    ...
);
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm trying to avoid using "Views".

Comment: why dont you add the term itself instead of the id?

Comment: @MohammedShameem The "product" node links to the nid, not the term. Can I do that EFQ?